# ubuntu-software (gnome-software) crashes after openinig

Tags: gnome, software-center

I get this error in command after opening Ubuntu-software:

```
(ubuntu-software:12472): GsPlugin-WARNING **: failed to load cached icon vino_preferences-desktop-remote-desktop.png: Failed to open file '/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-updates-main/vino_preferences-desktop-remote-desktop.png': No such file or directory Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The program will crash after 2-3 seconds.
I tried to remove and install it again but it did not work, I also tried sudo apt-get update and upgrade but they did not work either.
Why the program gives error about Remote Desktop sharing?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you're using?

Comment: sorry for late reply, I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS